# handling nested arrays in REACT/JSX

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

So I am using gatsbyjs and react to build a webpage. Now I have two nested arrays A and B, that both have two subarrays.

```
A = [['a'],['b']];
B = [['COQ', 'CCC'], ['CCCM', 'CK']];
```

I would like to present these two arrays on a webpage like this:

component A:

```
'a': 'COQ', 'CCC'
```

component B:

```
'b': 'CCCM', 'CK'
```

I know I probably should use .map() but I am not quite getting the trick.

My code:

```js
import React from "react"

const Test = () => {
  const fileNames = [["a"], ["b"]]
  const test = [
    ["COQ", "CCC"],
    ["CCCM", "CK"],
  ]

  // function dispChem(p2, index) {
  //     return p2[index];
  // }
  
  return (
    <div>
      Hi
      <div>
        <ul>
          {fileNames.map((fileName, index) => (
            <div key={fileName}>
              <li>
                {fileName}
                {test.map((res, index) => (
                  <div key={index}>
                    {res}
                    {console.log(res)}
                    {console.log(index)}
                  </div>
                ))}
              </li>
            </div>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Test
```

the result:

```
Hi
a
COQCCC
CCCMCK
b
COQCCC
CCCMCK
```

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: Dear @Zelinp, 
On your every run of filename.map(), you everytime run test.map()

```
    <ul>
        {fileNames.map((fileName, index) => (
            <li key={index}>{fileName + ": " + test[index].join(", ")}</li>
        ))}
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the index you get from your first `.map()` to get the associated array from `test`. Then you can use `.join()` on it to turn it into a string which you can concatenate with the `fileName`.

```
{fileNames.map((fileName, index) =>
  <div key={fileName}>
    <li>
      {`${fileName}: ${test[index].join(', ')}`}
    </li>
  </div>
)}
```

See example below:

```js
const Test = () => {
    const fileNames = [['a'], ['b']];
    const test = [['COQ', 'CCC'], ['CCCM', 'CK']];

    return (
        <div>
            Hi
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {fileNames.map((fileName, index) =>
                        <div key={fileName}>
                            <li>
                                {`${fileName}: ${test[index].join(', ')}`}
                            </li>
                        </div>


                    )}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer the 2 arrays into one object.

```js
const fileNames = [['a'], ['b']];
const test = [['COQ', 'CCC'], ['CCCM', 'CK']];

const newFiles = fileNames.map((f, index)=>{
  //console.log(f, index);
  return {[f]:test[index]};
});
console.log(newFiles);
```

Comment: Thank you Eric. Your answer gives me a new perspective.